# Problems with the font size of a Figure

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontsize

I've been working with a font size on 10pt. When I included a figure the font size is evidently larger than 10pt, something that I cannot overlook. I'll let the preamble code below, as well as the capture of the compiled result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.10in, 8.85in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\makesc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\the\parindent}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
  {\makebox[\mylength][l]{\Roman{section}.}}
  {0pt}
  {\makesc}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{.3\baselineskip}

\title{Fourier Transform Spectroscopy }
\author{Miqueas \\ \scriptsize{\textit{Electronics}}\\\scriptsize{\textit{Universidad}}\\\scriptsize{\textit{miqueasegamero@hotmail.com}}}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}. 


\noindent \scriptsize{\scriptsize{\textit{Abstract}: The present article aims to introduce the concept of optical spectroscopy, emphasizing and presenting a brief analysis of the Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy (FTS) technique, which is translated into Spanish as Fourier Transform Spectroscopy.}}

\noindent \scriptsize{\textit{Palabras clave:} Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy}
    

\section{Introduction} 

Spectroscopy is a technique that is based on exploiting the interaction between light and materials, taking advantage of the physical effects resulting from this interaction. Some of these effects on materials are \ textit {light absorption}, \ textit {light emission} or \ textit {changes in optical phase}. There are also several spectroscopy methods, such as the one that uses the variation of the light source (usually a laser) to study the absorption of a material. However, for the purposes of this report it is important to take as a starting point the method that is based on the spectral decomposition of a light source, commonly white since it has a wide spectrum of wavelengths. The apparatus used for this type of analysis are called interferometers, the operation of which will be briefly illustrated below.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Esquema de longitudes de onda.PNG}
\caption{Vista superior de una onda monocromática}
\label{fig:longitud_de_onda}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How would you solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. If I take xour preamble and add some text as well as an example caption, I can't see any font size difference.

Comment: you could scale the whole image to be smaller, with `\includegraphics[scale=..]` ir better generate the original image with different font size.

Comment: Ok leandriis, I'm gonna include it. David I'm about to try that

Comment: David's suggestion does not work. Leandriis, I've uploaded a bunch of code of the original work

Comment: Your revised MWE does not have any `figure` environment. It also does not compile because there is no `\end{document}`. Please provide something that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: Sorry for that Peter, I'm kinda new in this, I've added what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your preamble, or use the font size to match the main font of the document.

```
\usepackage{caption}  % added
    \captionsetup[figure]{font={scriptsize,rm},%
    justification=centering,%
    singlelinecheck=false}
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{caption}  % added
    \captionsetup[figure]{font={scriptsize,rm},%
    justification=centering,%
    singlelinecheck=false}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.10in, 8.85in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\makesc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\the\parindent}
%__________________________________________________________________________________
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
  {\makebox[\mylength][l]{\Roman{section}.}}
  {0pt}
  {\makesc}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{.3\baselineskip}

\title{Fourier Transform Spectroscopy }
\author{Miqueas \\ \scriptsize{\textit{Electronics}}\\\scriptsize{\textit{Universidad}}\\\scriptsize{\textit{miqueasegamero@hotmail.com}}}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\noindent \scriptsize{\scriptsize{\textit{Abstract}: The present article aims to introduce the concept of optical spectroscopy, emphasizing and presenting a brief analysis of the Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy (FTS) technique, which is translated into Spanish as Fourier Transform Spectroscopy.}}

\noindent \scriptsize{\textit{Palabras clave:} Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy}    

\section{Introduction} 

Spectroscopy is a technique that is based on exploiting the interaction between light and materials, 
taking advantage of the physical effects resulting from this interaction. Some of these effects on materials are 
\ textit {light absorption}, \ textit {light emission} or \ textit {changes in optical phase}. There are also several
spectroscopy methods, such as the one that uses the variation of the light source (usually a laser) to study the absorption
of a material. However, for the purposes of this report it is important to take as a starting point the method that
is based on the spectral decomposition of a light source, commonly white since it has a wide spectrum of wavelengths. 
The apparatus used for this type of analysis are called interferometers, the operation of which will be briefly illustrated below.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth, height=50pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \caption{Vista superior de una onda monocromática}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**Solution #2**

Instead of adding the package `caption` change this lines in your document to keep `10pt` as the default font size instead of `scriptsize`

```
\noindent {\scriptsize{\textit{Abstract}: The present article aims to introduce the concept of optical spectroscopy, emphasizing and presenting a brief analysis of the Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy (FTS) technique, which is translated into Spanish as Fourier Transform Spectroscopy.}}

\noindent {\scriptsize{\textit{Palabras clave:} Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy} }
```

Comment: Thank you Simon. It works!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the caption font size is 10pt, but the rest of the text is not. This is because of the `\scriptsize`-command(s) in your document: It switches the size of all the following text to scriptsize (which is 7pt in your document), not only the text in curly brackets. Try `{\scriptsize text}` to keep the size change local or use `\normalsize` when you want to return to normal font size.

Alternatively, if you really want to have all your text in scriptsize, you can adapt the font size of the caption by using `\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % only needed for the example picture
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption} % adapt captions.

\begin{document}
   \setlength{\parskip}{1em}
   
   \noindent%
   % The scope keeps the scriptsize-command local.
   {\scriptsize\textit{Abstract}: The present article aims to introduce the concept of optical spectroscopy, emphasizing and presenting a brief analysis of the Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy (FTS) technique, which is translated into Spanish as Fourier Transform Spectroscopy.}
   
   \noindent%
   % Alternative: first use \scriptsize, and later \normalsize.
   \scriptsize\textit{Palabras clave:} Fourier-Transform Spectroscopy\normalsize
   
   \section{Introduction} 
   \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{test}
   \end{figure}
   
   % All the text behind the figure is in normal size.
   Spectroscopy is a technique that is based on exploiting the interaction between light and materials.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Gonna check that